# Obj-C not compiling?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode, I made a C++ project. Later, I thought I'd try to learn Obj-C. I renamed the file from 'main.cpp' to 'main.m'.

I provided the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Programming is fun!");

    [pool drain];

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled, and got the following:

"_objc_msgSend", referenced from:

"_NSLog", referenced from:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:

"_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:

"___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't linking against the correct libraries.

The easiest approach is probably to create a new objective-c xcode project and copy your files over.

Comment: Thanks. I see Command Line Tool projects with C, C++, Core Data, Core Foundation, Core Services, and Foundation. Which would I pick for Obj-C?

Comment: @Phil, I think Foundation is what you want... I've only used XCode for iOS so I'm not sure.